# Load images one after another in a sequence.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to use JQuery to load 2 images after the page has loaded. I would like to request and load one image at a time. I tried this, but the requests and loads are happening simultaneously. First image should be come from 'src' and second from'data-src' html attributes.

```
<img id="image4" src="image/large.jpg" width="100%" data-src="image/full-size.jpg" />
```

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Can you post your JS code also?

Comment: $('img').bind('load', function() {
    $.get(img.attr('src'));
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your JS, I believe this is what you want:

```
var img = $("#image4");
var image1Url = img.attr("src");
var image2Url = img.attr("data-src");

$.get(image1Url)
   .done(function () {
      $.get(image2Url);
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this work for you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('img[data-src]').each(function( key, value ){
    var _this = $(this);
    var bigImage = _this.attr('data-src');        
    _this.after('<img class="preLoadingImage'+key+' hide" src="' + bigImage + '" />');
    
    $('.preLoadingImage'+key).one('load',function(){        
        _this.addClass('hide');
        $(this).removeClass('hide');
    });    
});

});
```

```css
.hide{ display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image4" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Loading_icon.gif" 
    width="100%" data-src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/ZhGEqAP.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you want this but take a look

JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#image4").after("<img src='" + $("#image4").attr("data-src") + "' width='100%' />");
  },2000);
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image4" src="image/large.jpg" width="100%" data-src="image/full-size.jpg" />
```

Comment: I don't want to delay in image loading.